# multiple SLF4J bindings in Hive - Hortonworks sandbox

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

While running Hive query in Hortonworks sandbox (HDP2.3 Pig and Hive Rev6), I am getting this warning. And nothing is happening after this. Hive table is also not getting created. What to do?

> [root@sandbox Lab7.1]# hive -f wh_visits.hive  SLF4J: Class path
>   contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1.2.3.2.0-2950-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch
>   YARN applications. SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1.2.3.2.0-2950-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.2.0-2950.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in file: `/etc/hive/2.3.2.0-2950/0/hive-log4j.properties`

Comment: Did you see the explanation in [http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings).

Comment: The SLF4J messages are just garbage to be ignored. Now, if _"nothing is happening after this"_, I would make a guess: Hive is trying to connect to *(a)* the Metastore service but it is not started/not responding, or *(b)* directly to the database server (MySQL?) but (...), and/or *(c)* to the YARN Timeline Server but (...) >> AFAIK you have to wait a looooong time before Hive reports a time-out and let you know what is the root cause.

Comment: yes your are right. i have ignored the warning. this is not a show stopper. But what i have observed is sometimes it takes long time to complete the job or return the hive prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and fixed it by doing below:

There are two jar files with the same name but in different path.
In my case it was 'slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar'.
Just rename one of them and then retry your thing. This fixed my problem.

```
[hadoop@hadoopsrvr01 ~]$ ls -lrt /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 hadoop hadoop 12244 Sep 10  2019 /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
[hadoop@hadoopsrvr01 ~]$ ls -lrt /opt/HBase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 hadoop hadoop 12244 Oct  5  2019 /opt/HBase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
[hadoop@hadoopsrvr01 ~]$

[hadoop@hadoopsrvr01 ~]$ mv /opt/HBase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar /opt/HBase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar.15072020
[hadoop@hadoopsrvr01 ~]$ ls -lrt /opt/HBase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar*
-rw-r--r--. 1 hadoop hadoop 12244 Oct  5  2019 /opt/HBase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar.15072020
[hadoop@hadoopsrvr01 ~]$
```